# Best practice for app integrations

Tags: user-expectation, web-app, email, integrations

We have an app that allows you to integrate with Zoom. So basically, from our app, when the user adds Zoom, it will ask them to login in to their Zoom account which would then install our app in Zoom.

Do we need to send an email to our users informing them that the integration was successful? Or does Zoom handle that?

What is the purpose of these emails? Is it for security - ie, in case someone used your credentials or installed the app without your authorization?

I'm confused on who handles what.

Comment: Hi, I think your best bet would be to reach out to Zoom's integrations support team. They should have some guiding documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the email notification is to surface security-relevant events to a user who may not be using the app at the moment, so in case there's unauthorized activity, the user can take steps to mitigate the breach.

It's not necessary to send an email as a success message. If the user clicked a button to authorize the integration, I'd expect to be returned back to the app after the authorization, at which point I can immediately continue with the task I need the integration for. For the purpose of communicating success, email is way too distant, delayed and just generally overkill.

For app integrations, this means the best practice is highly contextual:

- If you have an app that has no real data associated with it and which doesn't really function without the integration, there's little point sending out an email yourself.
- If you have an app that does have sensitive data associated with it, to which the integration is merely a QoL feature, then it depends how much access the integration has to the rest of the data. If the integration only is there to generate a link at a more convenient place, there may not be a need to send an email to the user. But if the integration would be able to access various personal information (contacts, calendar, email history, etc.), informing the user prior to making the connection what effects the authorization will have and, in case this authorization may be an attack vector, how to undo it quickly may be better.